# Can I replace a Pentium P6200 CPU with a core i5 2450M?

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard

I have an old Lenovo G560 laptop. It currently has a Lenovo motherboard (model: 20042), and an [Intel Pentium P6200](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/50176/intel-pentium-processor-p6200-3m-cache-2-13-ghz.html) processor.

I have another laptop with a motherboard that went bad a few years back, and I'm currently scavenging it for parts, to upgrade/improve my already aging computer. One of these parts is an [Intel Core i5 2450M](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53452/intel-core-i5-2450m-processor-3m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html) processor.

If this processor was compatible with the laptop and its motherboard, it can provide me with a much needed performance boost.
I was wondering if this processor can fit and work in the laptop.

My only concern is that, if I experiment and install it (sockets are physically similar), but it wasn't compatible, it might cause electrical damage, or otherwise.

Will this swap work?

Comment: No; It won’t work; The two processors are incompatible with one another.

Comment: Here is an Intel article that will assist you in understanding this.   https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000006047/processors.html

Comment: @Ramhound Could you provide more details, about why you reached this conclusion? Is it about socket types (PPGA988 vs. PGA988) or  something else?

Comment: The intel article I posted has most of what you want. Open up each link and you will find some socket tables

Comment: @John This article is about desktop processors. Which part are you referring to?

Comment: @user1217172 - Beyond the fact the newer processor is one of two sockets, is an entirely different generation of processor, and two generations of processors were not compatible with one another even when they were new?

Comment: I was just using the general comments about sockets.  "Which sockets do the Intel® Core™ i5 Desktop Processors use?"   The thinking applies desktop or laptop.

Comment: The sockets are mentioned in the links I provided in my question above. The current processor uses PGA988, while the intended replacement uses PPGA988. According to https://community.intel.com/t5/Processors/Differance-between-PGA988-and-PPGA988-CPU-socket/td-p/295915, they can work with one another. However, I was looking for any more obstructions along the way, given the fact that they are of a different caliber.